# Entity Framework avoiding [NotMapped] attribute in release mode

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, visual-studio-2017

I have recently upgraded my project to .NET Framework 4.5 from 4.0. After completing all tasks mentioned in this [MSDN Migration Guide](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff657133(v=vs.110).aspx), I added some changes to the models for supporting Oracle database.

The models are shown here:

```
namespace KYC_v4.Models
{
    [Serializable]
    public class Organization
    {
       public int OrganizationID { get; set; }

       [Required]
       [Display(Name = "OrganizationName", ResourceType = typeof(Resources.Home))]
       [MaxLength(200)]
       public string OrganizationName { get; set; }

       public virtual List<UserGroup> Groups{get;set;}

       public OrganizationDetails Details { get; set; }

       public int UserID { get; set; }

       [NotMapped]
       [MaxLength(100)]
       public string membersCount { get; set; }

       [NotMapped]
       public List<CheckOrgPermissionViewModel> CheckPermission { get; set; }
    }
}

public class CheckOrgPermissionViewModel {
    public string Permissiontype { get; set; }
    public bool isTrue { get; set; }
}
```

It is running normally when I debug from Visual Studio, but when I try to host it in IIS server, I get this error:

[image: Error screenshot]

What I have tried so far:

1. From other answers about similar issues, I tried to remove the reference  `System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;`  in the above files - did not work
2. Tried copying the `.dll` file from the path

   ```
   C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations\v4.0_4.0.0.0__31bf3856ad364e35\System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.dll**
   ```

   to the `bin` directory of the application
3. Updated the installed NuGet packages `using Update-Package -reinstall -Project "Kyc v4"`

None of the above works for me, and if you are wondering - I do not have the `DbSet` for the models mentioned in the error in my `DbContext`, so my guess is the `[NotMapped]` attribute is being ignored by Entity Framework (`6.1.3`) for some reason. The version in my `System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations` reference is `4.0.0.0` and runtime is given as `v4.0.30319`

Any help is appreciated. Thank you

Comment: Use view models (and your view models should be in a separate folder - say `ViewModels` so they are not associated with EF)

Comment: If I do that , Can I use it along with the regular Modals using [NotMapped] without any Issues? Also, If that is the case Why Am I able to run the project without any problems While debugging in iisexpress

Comment: Stop using `[NotMapped]` and data models in your view and use view models. And view models do not contain properties which are data models.

Comment: Is [NotMapped] deprecated. And If yes Why is it not giving me issues in other places where I use it?

Comment: Not as far as I know.

Comment: Then I cannot understand what is the problem in using it with data models

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/142702/discussion-between-stephen-muecke-and-insomniac).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end, I have found out that the issue was with the `Visual studio IDE` itself. It was not cleaning the old references while doing "Clean"/"Build" or "Rebuild" for some reason so the references were conflicting and causing confusion with the `System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Schema`. So I manually deleted the old files and published to a new empty directory.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried​ to put the annotation [Key] on OrganizationID?

```
Serializable] public class Organization  { 
   [Key]
     public int OrganizationID { get; set; }  }
```

Answer (score 0):

I had this issue and it took a while to figure out the problem. Basically, I had 3 projects:

1. **DbContext Project** - this was used for data migrations and Entity Framework code
2. **Models Project** - these contained the models referenced by the DbContext project (and included the [NotMapped] tag. This is .NET 2.0 standard projectas it shared models to an Xamarin iOS and Android app project.
3. **ASP.NET MVC Project** - this contained the WebUI and referenced both of the above.

The problem was that I was using the Nuget package for:

**System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations**

For the **Models** and **Web** projects, but not the **DbContext** project.

I needed this for the .NET Standard project as I couldn't reference the normal .NET library (maybe not the best project organisation, but its what I had)

The solution was reference the nuget version of 'System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations'  in all the projects.

When I did that and ran Update-Database it worked fine.